# Adding a function to onclick event by Javascript!

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is it possible to add a `onclick` event to any button by jquery or something like we add class?

```
function onload()
{

//add a something() function to button by id

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Calling your function `something` binding the `click` event on the element with a ID

```
$('#id').click(function(e) {
    something();
});

$('#id').click(something);

$('#id').bind("click", function(e) { something(); });
```

Live has a slightly difference, it will bind the event for any elements added, but since you are using the ID it probably wont happen, unless you remove the element from the DOM and add back later on (with the same ID).

```
$('#id').live("click", function(e) { something(); });
```

Not sure if this one works in any case, it adds the attribute `onclick` on your element: (I never use it)

```
$('#id').attr("onclick", "something()");
```

**Documentation**

- [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [Attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: some comment would've been neat for these lines. He may not get what they are good for.

Comment: I needed to set the click function when a checkbox was checked. The only method that worked for me was bind. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You could write it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function(){
    // do something when clicked
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id').click(function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Something like the following should work.

```
$('#button_id').click(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```