# JavaScript disabled attribute not the same as Enabled attribute?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm having some weird issues with the `disabled` attribute of an asp button and JavaScript, probably due to my lack of experience, but anyway...

As I understand from this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526666/1222199), setting the `disabled` attribute makes the element disabled. **Unless** you set it like so; `element.disabled = false;`

So, that's what I do in my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckOne(inChkBox) {
        ... irrelevant code goes here ...
        var rejectButton = document.getElementById('btnReject');
        if (inChkBox.checked) {
            rejectButton.disabled = false;
            rejectButton.className = 'Enabled';
        } else {
            rejectButton.disabled = true;
            rejectButton.className = 'Disabled';
        }
    }
</script>
<input type='checkbox' name='chkRejectLineItem' onchange='CheckOne(this);' runat="server"/>
```

This seems to trigger and work fine (the cssclass changes at the very least...) apart from the fact that my button is still disabled;

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProjectTimeReject" runat="server" Text="Reject Selected" OnClientClick="LineItemRejectReason();"  OnClick="btnProjectTimeReject_Click" Enabled="False" CssClass="Disabled"/>
```

I know this, because the `OnClientClick` never gets called (for some reason, the server side code still gets called??). If I set the button to `Enabled="True"` then everything works as expected.

Is it because I'm using `Enabled="True"` initially and I should instead use `rejectButton.removeAttribute('disabled')` in the enable/disable JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of console debugging and googling the same thing different ways, I found the following [solution/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220029/1222199).

```
var rejectButton = document.getElementById('btnPLReject');
if (inChkBox.checked) {
    rejectButton.disabled = false;
    rejectButton.className = 'Enabled';
    $('#btnPLReject').bind("click", function() { LeaveRejectReason(); });
} else {
    rejectButton.disabled = true;
    rejectButton.className = 'Disabled';
}
```

This causes the button to trigger the JavaScript/Client side code AND then the Server side code...where as it was only doing the Server side code before...

I need some panadol now.